# String Bugged in C

Tags: c, string, printing

I have a weird bug on a string in C. I use this code to read the string (the code reads a string with spaces and divide in 2 parts)

```
for (i=0;i<cantidad;i++){
    fscanf(abrir,"%[^\n]\n",nombre);
    pch = strtok (nombre,"  ");
    j=0;
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        if (j==0){
            strcpy(arc[i][0], pch);
            j=1;
        }else if(j==1){
            strcpy(arc[i][1], pch);
        }
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

the code  seems to be fine if I give the string "Valencia Caracas" to the code, but when you use something as

```
printf("%saaaaa",arc[0][1]);
```

the print will show me something like this:

```
aaaaaracas
```

Why does this happen?
EDITED: was trying to do it fast cause i have a lot of stuff and did not see my typing errors srry

Comment: What is the declaration of `arc`?

Comment: `char arc[contador][2][100];`

Comment: I have several questions: (i) What exactly is `src`? Did you mean `arc`? And in any case, (ii) what is `arc`? A 2D array of `char*` pointers? Have you assigned enough space to store strings in these pointers? (iii) Why use `fscanf(abrir,"%[^\n]\n",nombre);` when `fgets()` would suffice (and reduce the risk of buffer overflows)? (iv) `printf(%saaaaa,src[0][1]);` won't even compile without quotation marks.

Comment: I second the questions from @squeamishossifrage. You really need to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 because it is hard for us to guess what you're up to.  Ideally, the code will read from standard input.  One question: are you one Windows, and did you open the text file as a binary file?  Could CR (`'\r'`) characters be confusing the output?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is probably right. `\r` is carriage return so it would write the string and move the location of output back to the first character on the line and output the `a`s over the original string

Comment: i'm using linux right now, and the thing is that i need to read a file that compares 2 strings, but when i try to do it, the second bugged string gives me an arror and cant do anything with it because when i try to strcmp the bugged strings just say that they are not equal.

Comment: Create an MCVE that shows what you see happening.  I can't guess what you're doing wrong.  Maybe `nombre` isn't big enough? The `arc` array worries me; there are lots of ways for that to go wrong.  The fact that you don't show printing such as `printf("nombre: <<%s>>\n", pch);` and `printf("pch <<%s>>\n", pch);` worries me too; I'd want that to know what is read, and what `strtok()` is identifying before I did anything much else.  So, please create the MCVE with minimal input data (clearly identified in the question) showing the problem.  Note that `FILE *abrir = stdin;` might be useful.

Comment: Even if you are running linux, the file could still use the CR+LF line endings.